# How many multiplications and additions does it take to compute an FFT of a signal?

Tags: fft

How many multiplications/additions does it take to execute an FFT operation in terms of the length of the signal $N$ and the number of FFT bins $M$? I don't want an answer in terms of big O, but rather in terms of just $N$ and $M$.

Comment: Well, FFT is just a class of methods: What are you expecting? And, frankly, there's no difference between N and M – an FFT always transforms an N-element vector.

Comment: maybe it would help if you could explain *why* you (think) you need this number – while the O() notation is useful to give one a feeling of the order of complexity, absolute numbers are largely meaningless, because on real CPUs, memory bandwidth is usually the dominating factor for large transforms, and setup / data copying for small; in hardware, the numbers are hardly helpful, because depending on your use case, you'd multiplex, iteratively or fully parallely implement an FFT.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in more involved numbers of operations, you can check [A modified split-radix FFT with fewer arithmetic operations](http://ftp.fftw.org/newsplit.pdf), by Johnson and Frigo, IEEE Transactions on Signal Processing, 2007, authors of the "Fastest Fourier Transform in the West" (FFTW). For instance, they claim that the complexity of the classic radix-2 is about:

$$ 5N\log_2 N$$

while the split-radix yields:

$$4N \log_2 N − 6N + 8\,,$$

and they achieved the improvement:

$$\frac{34}{9} N \log_2 N − \frac{124 }{27 }N − 2 \log_2 N − \frac{2}{9}
(−1)^{\log_2 N} \log_2 N + \frac{16}{27}
 (−1)^{\log_2 N} + 8\,.$$

As said by others, you can see this number depends on implementations, and that the actual gain is subtle.